# Can two Hive Partitions Share One Set of Files?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, partition

A typical question is can a Hive partition be made up of multiple files. My question is the inverse. Can multiple Hive partitions point to the same file? I'll start with what I mean, then the use case.

What I mean:

```
Hive Partition      File Name
20120101            /file/location/201201/file1.tsv
20120102            /file/location/201201/file1.tsv
20120103            /file/location/201201/file1.tsv
```

The Use Case: Over the past many years, we've been loading data into Hive in monthly format. So it looked like this:

```
Hive Partition      File Name
201201              /file/location/201201/file1.tsv
201202              /file/location/201202/file1.tsv
201203              /file/location/201203/file1.tsv
```

But now the months are too large, so we need to partition by day. So we want the new files starting with 201204 to be daily:

```
Hive Partition      File Name
20120401            /file/location/20120401/file1.tsv
20120402            /file/location/20120402/file1.tsv
20120403            /file/location/20120403/file1.tsv
```

But we want all the existing partitions to be redone into daily as well, so we would partition it as I propose above. I suspect this would actually work no problem, except that I suspect Hive would re-read the same datafile N times for each additional partition defined against the file. For example, in the very first "What I Mean" code block above, partitions 20120101..20120103 all point to file 201201/file1.tsv. So if the query has:

```
and partitionName >= '20120101' and partitionName <= '20120103"
```

Would it read "201201/file1.tsv" three times to answer the query? Or will Hive be smart enough to know it's only necessary to scan "201201/file1.tsv" once?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Hive will only scan the file(s) once. I finally decided to just give it a shot and run a query and find out.

First, I set up my data set like this in the filesystem:

```
tableName/201301/splitFile-201301-xaaaa.tsv.gz
tableName/201301/splitFile-201301-xaaab.tsv.gz
...
tableName/201301/splitFile-201301-xaaaq.tsv.gz
```

Note that even though I have many files, this is equivalent for Hive to having one giant file for the purposes of this question. If it makes it easier, pretend I just pasted a single file above.

Then I set up my Hive table with partitions like this:

```
alter table tableName add partition ( dt = '20130101' ) location '/tableName/201301/' ;
alter table tableName add partition ( dt = '20130102' ) location '/tableName/201301/' ;
...
alter table tableName add partition ( dt = '20130112' ) location '/tableName/201301/' ;
```

The total size of my files in tableName/201301 was about 791,400,000 bytes (I just eyeballed the numbers and did basic math). I ran the job:

```
hive> select dt,count(*) from tableName where dt >= '20130101' and dt <= '20130112' group by dt ;
```

The JobTracker reported:

```
Counter     Map             Reduce    Total
Bytes Read  795,308,244     0         795,308,244
```

So it only read the data once. HOWEVER... the query output was all jacked:

```
20130112    392606124
```

So it thinks there was only one "dt", and that was the final "partition", and it had all rows. So you have to be very careful including "dt" in your queries when you do this, it would appear.

Comment: I'm marking my answer correct with a caveat that Joe K's solution below, although initially wrong, does point out a pretty good alternate solution, having a "monthly" table and a "daily" table and requiring the analyst to do the same SELECT against both tables with a UNION. It seems possible this will be required long-term if there are negative side-effects of defining the partitions this way. I will come back and comment if I do find such negative side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Hive would scan the file multiple times.</strike> Earlier answer was incorrect. Hive reads the file once, but generates "duplicate" records. The issue is that the partition columns are included in the total record, so for each record in the file, you would get multiple records in Hive, each with different partition values.

Do you have any way to recover the actual day from the earlier data? If so, the ideal way to do things would be to totally repartition all the old data. That's painful, but it's a one-time cost and would save you having a really weird Hive table.

You could also move to having two Hive tables: the "old" one partitioned by month, and the "new" one partitioned by day. Users could then do a union on the two when querying, or you could create a view that does the union automatically.

Comment: I like your solution about two tables and doing a UNION. Re-partitioning is of course POSSIBLE but is a pretty hefty project. I did a test, and it looks like you're incorrect about Hive reading the file(s) multiple times.

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I edited instead of deleting since the rest of what I said still makes sense.